# QObjectPicker in Qt3D and setting PointPicking does not work

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qt3d, pyside2

I want to use point picker to pick (get) coordinates of my points in a point cloud. That is why I want to set `QPickingSettings` to `PointPicking` but it seems that cannot be done. Events sent to method `mouse_event` are of type `QPickEvent` and NOT `QPickPointEvent`. What am I doing wrong?

```py
self.picker = Qt3DRender.QObjectPicker(self)
picking_settings = Qt3DRender.QPickingSettings(self.picker)
picking_settings.setFaceOrientationPickingMode(
    Qt3DRender.QPickingSettings.FrontAndBackFace)  
# set QObjectPicker to PointPicking:
picking_settings.setPickMethod(
    Qt3DRender.QPickingSettings.PointPicking)
picking_settings.setPickResultMode(
    Qt3DRender.QPickingSettings.NearestPick)
picking_settings.setWorldSpaceTolerance(.5)

self.picker.setHoverEnabled(True)
self.picker.setDragEnabled(True)

def mouse_event(e):
    # do something
    # e should be QPickPointEvent type
    pass

self.picker.moved.connect(mouse_event)
self.picker.pressed.connect(mouse_event)
self.picker.clicked.connect(mouse_event)
self.picker.released.connect(mouse_event)
self.addComponent(self.picker)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the python API, but you should not create your own instance of QPickingSettings but use the one that exists as a property of the instance of [QRenderSettings](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qt3drender-qrendersettings.html) (that is a singleton).

If you're using the [Qt3DWindow](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qt3dextras-qt3dwindow.html) from Qt3DExtras, it will provide an accessor to the QRenderSettings instance.

Otherwise, you'll need to create an instance of QRenderSettings and add it as a component of an entity. By convention we tend to use the root of the scene graph.

Comment: Thanks. `QRenderSettings` instance is available via `Qt3DWindow` and there I can set to pointpicking. Now it works!